# Updates on Setup Project C# keeping Connection String

Tags: c#, clickonce, app-config, updates, setup-project

I need check for updates in my project using a "Setup Project". I've notice that if i use a "Setup Project", all settings that were edited by the client are maintained. I also notice that if I use ClickOnce overwrites with settings that come with the compilation of the project, programmatically can I get the userSettings from the previous version, but I can not overwrite the Connection String to do the same.

With a "Setup Project", I can keep the ConnectionString settings, but my application do not check for updates online.

With ClickOnce, my application checks for updates before start, but when install an update, remove the modify settings, overwriting the correct ConnectionString.

My main interest is to keep the ConnectionString from one version to another. Unfortunately, i don't know the ConnectionString used by the client, so I can't compile a Release and Debug configuration.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using to create the setup project?

Comment: In first time, im using vs 2010. But i have vs 2013 too

Comment: VS 2013 doesn't matter that much because there is no setup project to build an MSI install, so if you want to continue using MSI setups you'll need to stick with 2010 or use another tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in support for automatic check for upgrades with setup projects. I believe InstallShield offers it as a service if you use their tool.

Typically your updates would need to be in a database at your company's web site, by version, ProductCode guid and UpgradeCode guid, accessible with a web service. Your app would call this web service to ask about upgrades - they would have the same UpgradeCode but a higher version and a different ProductCode. If you used a tool that supplied patches, you'd ask for patches with the same ProductCode but a higher version. By version I mean version of the MSI  product, not files. Whatever is available you'd download for the client if required.

Comment: As a matter of fact, setup projects are retired and people are encouraged to upgrade to Wix - with ClickOnce being an issue ;)